# SSIS package XML source

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

I am fairly new at SSIS (just FTR).

I have to import XML data from a DB2 database into SQL Server using SSIS packages. The XML is in CLOB/BLOB (depends on the table), which is - to my knowledge - not supported by the Microsoft DB2 driver, so I made a Java bridge, that takes an ID from a client and returns the XML. The bridge is accessed by a Visual Basic client (pre-compiled, and) executed as a Script task in SSIS. Performance is not a great priority at the moment (it is 7XMLs/sec). The XML returned from the bridge is stored in a variable, and since the bridge accepts one ID/request, the request scenar is in a Foreach Loop Container, that loops through the IDs received from an SQL task.

In the foreach loop there is the Visual Basic client that stores the XML, a Data flow to import data from the XML and store in a FlatFile target, and an another Visual Basic task, that shows the XML in a MsgBox().

The Data flow also has three elements: XML Source, Derived column, Flat file destination. The XML Source takes the XML data from a variable with a fix XML Schema (XSD), and sends the parsed data. The Derived column add the ID as a new column to the XML data and the FlatFile Target should save it (as mentioned earlier, for testing purpouses only).

When I start this package, everything goes well. In the Java bridge I see the communication and the XML sent back, the Data flow also returns without error, however it throws some warnings, and there are no lines lines written into the file. The second VB script shows the XML correctly.

The warning is with a number 0x80047076 about the unhandled outputs from the XML file (since I only intent to store just one part of it).

Any ideas, why isn't any data written into the file output?

SQL server 2005 sp1
Java SE 1.6 (u26 I think)
DB2 v. 9

The warning looks as follows:

> Warning: 0x80047076 at Import from XML, DTS.Pipeline: The output column "text" (965) on output "sum" (36) and component "XML Source" (1) is not subsequently used in the Data Flow task. Removing this unused output column can increase Data Flow task performance.

I tried to add an XML file 'hard coded' into the variable. I also checked the XML against its XSD using XML Spy. The XML is valid, but no data was written into the flat file.

When I try debugging, and add the variable into the watch, I get the XML slightly modified:
the "-s are backslashed, and after the standard XML header the new line character is also printed as the standard line feed: \n. Example:

> <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<extended-attributes><customer-value>A</customer-value> ...

However, the XML is printed normally (\n as line feed, \" as "), when showing it in a MsgBox, so my guess is, that this is only a not handled, direct print from C/C++/C# string representation.

Comment: Could you write a whole warning sentence? I know they can be quite verbose, but there might be some clue on it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to visualize the data before being passed to the flat file destination?

By your description it sounds as if the data is not reaching it.

To add a data viewer to it, follow the steps in this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140318.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I checked it in a grid view, and no data is going through, so evidently there going to be some trouble in the XML Source. Any guesses?

Comment: @Mensfeld Since you only have 3 elements on the data flow, the issue is either in the data source not being able to get data from the file or the derived column not passing the elements through. Have you tried visualizing the data between the `data source` and `derived column` tasks? If there is data going between those two, then the issue is at the derived column task. If not, the issue is in the data source.

Comment: as I wrote above, there were no data between the data source and the derived column, so it must be the XML source. The XSD is the same that was used to generate the XML, and when running, it reports no error.

Comment: @Mensfeld How are you loading the xml data from the variable to the data source? If you want, you can take a screenshot, upload it to a image host and post the link here.

Comment: I can't upload images (too few point on this site). The images are at: http://kami.sama.szm.com/ssis1.PNG and http://kami.sama.szm.com/ssis2.PNG the data is loaded by the Visual Basic client from the Java bridge and stored in a variable. I already checked that, the XML is stored correctly.

Comment: I am running out of ideas here. Try creating a xml file with the same data in the variable. Then load it in the data source changing the "data access mode" to file location. If it works, then you have isolated the issue.